# Intermittent Wireless After Uninstalling Google Chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, wireless-networking

My dad uninstalled Google Chrome from his laptop and went back to IE. Now he only gets intermittent wireless anywhere he goes. What could be causing this? Could uninstalling Chrome have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it didn't happen too long ago, use windows system restore. Revert to a date before you removed chrome.

You shouldn't lose any data (I haven't) when you do this and it has saved me a few times.

Answer (score 0):

While I'd love to say that switching to IE kills your Internet, it's probably something that just happened at the same time as your Chrome uninstallation. It can't hurt to see what happens when you reinstall Chrome, though. Go down the procedure:

1. Reinstall your wireless drivers.
2. Reset your modem and wireless.
3. Disable your WiFi antenna, then reenable it.
4. Use Windows' diagnostics tools.

If after that it still doesn't work, it was certainly a coincidence.

You may be mixing up wireless with Internet though. In that case, Chrome has a much higher chance of having interfered with that. Look through your IE settings and see if anything's wonky.